# Superfluous white when using matplotlib pcolor

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a 101x145 matrix as a heatmap using matplotlib. However, there is superfluous white on the top and right of the plot. How do I get rid of it?

Consider the following example:

```
import cPickle as pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolor(np.zeros((101,145)))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fig.tight_layout`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout)
does what you want. It accounts for all the subplots, axis labels, axis ticklables, etc. and try to stretch what is plotted in order to leave as less empty space as possible. You can also decide the padding and the box, in figure coordinates, within which tight_layout should work.

[Here](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html#tight-layout-guide) are some examples.

A word of warning: `tight_layout` works only with subplots not with `Axes` objects